# Not able to access tomcat/webserver from nginx server/machine(Different machine)

Tags: nginx, tomcat, webserver

i am facing weird issue from yesterday. Couldn't access webserver/tomcat from different machine. My set up is like this

Nginx server (Different ip) ---> webserver(Different ip)

xyz.co --> nginx server --> webserver

I can access my webserver tomcat using directly from

`http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/myurl` ( This is fine from browser, but not ok from nginx server)

When it is getting access from nginx server it is not able to access.

I see this on nginx `error.log`

`2022/01/31 02:01:38 [crit] 12686#12686: *34821 connect() to xx.xx.xx.xx:8080 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: xyz.co, request: "GET /myurl HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/myurl", host: "xyz.co"`

`2022/01/31 02:01:38 [error] 12686#12686: *34821 open() "/srv/static/website/maintenance/500.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.70.135.162, server: jobpedia.net, request: "GET /myurl HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/myurl", host: "xyz.co"`

I have applied iptable rules also on webserver no luck :(

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -s nginx-server-ip/32 -j ACCEPT`

`sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 8080 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -s nginx-server-ip/32 -j ACCEPT`

my nginx config is like this

```
    proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
    rewrite ^/$ /myurl break;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    
    location /500.html {
                root  /srv/static/website/maintenance;
        }
```

Comment: A _"permission denied"_ in the proxy server suggests that there is a (rather restrictive) firewall on that server too.

Answer (score 1):

`setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on`

Just set this on `nginx`  server, it works